# A game with 330 pebbles

Tags: mathematics, strategy, combinatorics, game

Anastasia and Barnabas play a game that starts with $330$ pebbles in a bowl.
The game consists of two phases. The first phase looks as follows:

- First Anastasia announces an integer $A$ with $2\le A\le9$.
- Then Barnabas announces an integer $B$ with $2\le B\le9$ and $B\ne A$.

The second phase looks as follows:

- The two players alternately take pebbles out of the bowl. Anastasia makes the first move.
- In every move, Anastasia may either take $1$ pebble or $A$ pebbles.
- In every move, Barnabas  may either take $1$ pebble or $B$ pebbles.
- The player who takes the last pebble wins the game.

> **Question:** Which player is going to win this game?
>   (As usual, we assume that Anastasia and Barnabas both use optimal strategies.)

Comment: What happens if A = 5 and at one point there are 4 pebbles on the table and it's A's turn? It is considered a win?

Comment: @Marius: Then A will take 1 pebble, according to the rules.

Comment: No Alice and Bob? :o

Comment: If they're both using optimal strategies, then Anastasia chooses the optimal A, leaving Barnabas with having to settle for something less than optimal, so of course Anastasia wins. On the other hand, if they're both using optimal strategies, the optimal strategy would be to only play if you get to choose first.

Comment: +1 for more interesting names than just Alice and Bob. (And because it's an interesting puzzle)

Comment: @Devsman, Barnabas chooses *after* Anastasia has chosen, therefore Barnabas has more information, so he might be able to use the information about the moves Anastasia can make to choose a better strategy then Anastasia.

Comment: @Devsman Let's play Rock Paper Scissors : you can start and apply your better strategy, I will choose after you ;)

Comment: Given the instruments with which one plays, would not a good title have been "A Game of Stones"?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Answer

> Anastasia wins

Because

> Anastasia is the first to choose the integer and she chooses $A = 2$.
>
>  Anastasia should first reach a status where there's a number of pebbles left less than $B$.
>  To achieve this, on every Anastasia's turn we can say that there are
>
>     $B + n$ pebbles left
>
>  As long as $n > 2$, she can play whatever number.
>  When $n \leq 2$ Anastasia must play the correct number: if $n = 2$ she plays $1$, else if $n = 1$ she plays $2$.
>  The status after this move is either $B + 1$ or $B - 1$ and it's Barnabas' turn. He cannot win at this turn (because $B \geq 3$) and after his turn we have less than $B$ pebbles left.
>  Anastasia should now just make sure that after her turn there's an even number of pebbles left, so that Barnabas' can't win. On the last turn there's just 1 pebble left and it's Anastasia's turn.

Comment: I had the same idea but you beat me to it :)